# Inform user to add Metadata after Upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, metadata, notifications

Let's say users end up using different uploading methods and some of their files end up not being filled with metadata. We use SharePoint Online.

I want them to get a file/notification or something similar once a week letting them know that these specific files uploaded from them aren't filled have metadata.

It should be something lika a weekly alert.

I can not use Microsoft Flow

help would be really welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow is available for SharePoint Online as well. The only thing you need is download SharePoint Designer to make your own workflow.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=35491

As you are using SharePoint Online, you have access to workflow 2013 by default. 
Raj's example is a very good one. I will provide a simple one to help you get some idea of the the process

[image]

I set it to be 1 minute for test, you can set it according to your requirement.

Comment: thank a lot for the details answer. I will mark it as answered but was not able to try it. Not sure If  we are allowed to use or have SharePoint Designer.  Is there any Javascript that I would use as a webpart to come up with the same result

Comment: @Ed1995 You can accept as answer to mark the reply as answer I think. And sorry for I am not quite familiar with JavaScript, not sure if we can do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SP2013 workflows, you can set up a workflow that will notify on a periodic basis.

[Periodic Notifications](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/77f269/send-periodic-expiration-email-notifications-in-office-365-a/)

Without SP2013 workflows it's a little harder to pull off.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using SharePoint online

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific out-of-the-box solution for that but you can use other tools to make that possible. As mentioned by @BigRaj and @jerry_MSFT, *SharePoint Designer Workflows* could be the solutions to accomplish a custom solution. But, if you can develop some kind of code you can create your own solution, from the simplest to the most complex:

- *Reminder Workflow*: You can use any other workflow engine to create your own, tools like that are Nintex, K2 or Microsoft Flow (you mentioned that's not possible). Creation of workflows using these tools are so easy and not development skills are needed,
- *Scheduled Script*: You can create a PowerShell script to retrieve those files with no properties filled in and send a reminder email to the authors,
- *Scheduled Azure Function*: You can implement the same functionality as the previous solution but using an Azure Function. These function can be triggered every 5 minutes or any other proper schedule you consider better,
- *Custom Solution*: This is so big solution because you can implement what you consider here, from creating a custom workflow for SharePoint Online (javascript or .net) or a more deeper solution with much more functionality.

Hope this can guide you on your decision.

Comment: I have to check when I'm back a my practice place to see if we have access to SharePoint Designer .The best approach would be some javascript code that we can implement using webparts but my knowledge with javascript is not sufficient

Comment: Hope this link could be useful for you, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-the-sharepoint-workflow-services-client-side-object-model